# At same positioned game objects collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, unity, gameobject

In my game, I am creating two game objects at same position using Instantiate statement. Each generated object has box collider attached.

So I want to detect collision between them so I write following code.

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo){
   print("on collision stay");
}
```

But this statement not called. I generate two object using following code.

```
BallUtility.AddNormalCommonBall (normalBallPref, Vector3.zero);
BallUtility.AddNormalCommonBall (normalBallPref, Vector3.zero);
```

I need help in collision detection. I already post question in unity forum but I didn't get any reply from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collision events will only be detected under specific circumstances.

Each collider can be considered to have these relevant properties:

1. Is a **RigidBody** (or RigidBody2D) attached to it's GameObject, if not it is considered **Static**.
2. If it has a RigidBody, is it marked **Kinematic**?
3. Is the Collider marked **Trigger**?

The circumstances under which collisions are detected are summarized in this table:
[image]

[Source](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I detect my collision method running.